# Level sets of factors are different while calculating accuracy

Tags: r, r-factor

I built a random forest model. The predicted output and the actual output are factors. There are 19 classes to predict but one of these classes did not appear in the testing data set.

I then want to calculate the accuracy of the model, using this formula:

```
accuracy <- sum(ActualOutput==PredictedOutput, na.rm = TRUE) / length(PredictedOutput)
```

Which generates this error message:

> Error in Ops.factor(ActualOutput, PredictedOutput) :    level sets of
>   factors are different

`ActualOutput` has 19 levels and `PredictedOutput` has 18 levels. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I compare two factors with different levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962082/how-can-i-compare-two-factors-with-different-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have two outputs `ActualOutput` and `PredictedOutput` of same length but different levels

```
PredictedOutput <- factor(c("a", "b", "b"))
ActualOutput <- factor(c("a", "b", "c"))

sum(ActualOutput == PredictedOutput)

Error in Ops.factor(ActualOutput, PredictedOutput) : 
  level sets of factors are different
```

`PredictedOutput` has 2 levels, but `ActualOutput` has 3.  We want to set the levels of `PredictedOutput` to those of `ActualOutput`

```
PredictedOutput <- factor(PredictedOutput, levels=levels(ActualOutput))
```

Now `PredictedOutput` looks like

```
[1] a b b
Levels: a b c
```

And your formula should work

```
sum(ActualOutput == PredictedOutput)
[1] 2
```

If you have a small reproducible example, we may be of greater assistance

Comment: Such a great clarification and answer. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem if you transform your variable to character instead of factor? Can you build your model like that or you need factor type?

Generally, this is a training/testing datasets building issue. Sometimes when one of the classes has few observations you have to make sure you have some cases in both training and testing sets. Check some stratified sampling methods.

Can you give some more info on the package and command you used for the random forest model?

Comment: I need to keep the variables in factor form. I will definitely try stratified sampling methods. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: For the random forest model, I tried randomForest package. It contains useful training and predicting functions.