# How can I compare two factors with different levels?

Tags: r, r-factor

Is it possible to compare two factors of same length, but different levels? For example, if we have these 2 factor variables:

```
A <- factor(1:5)

str(A)
 Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5

B <- factor(c(1:3,6,6))

str(B)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","6": 1 2 3 4 4
```

If I try to compare them using, for example, the `==` operator:

```
mean(A == B)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in Ops.factor(A, B) : level sets of factors are different

Comment: Will you please explain what is meant by ***compare two factors***. It is not clear to me.

Comment: @user2100721 I am assuming they want to know the proportion of overlap. In example from my post, overlap is `3` out of `5`, `3/5 = 0.6`. Note that `TRUE/FALSE` is converted implicitly to `1/0`, i.e.: `TRUE + TRUE = 2`.

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks. Got your point.

Comment: @zx8754 Sorry for the noise, I forgot to wrap with `factor` earlier.  With microbenchmark, your solution is almost 2 times faster which is kind of surprising.

Comment: @zx8754 I added that option to your answer.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @zx8754 I am not at all concerned with rep :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert to character then compare:

```
# data
A <- factor(1:5)
B <- factor(c(1:3,6,6))

str(A)
# Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5
str(B)
# Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","6": 1 2 3 4 4

mean(A == B)
```

> Error in Ops.factor(A, B) : level sets of factors are different

```
mean(as.character(A) == as.character(B))
# [1] 0.6
```

Or another approach would be

```
mean(levels(A)[A] == levels(B)[B])
```

which is 2 times slower on a 1e8 dataset.

Comment: You might also look at `all.equal`, depending on exactly what it is you mean by 'compare'.

Comment: @David_B I am not sure how `all.equal` can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Converting  to `character` as in @zx8754's answer is the easiest solution to this problem, and probably the one you'd want to use almost always. Another option, though, is to correct the 2 variables so that they have the same levels. You might want to do this if you want to keep these variables as `factor` for some reason and don't want to have to clog up your code with repeated calls to `as.character`.

```
A <- factor(1:5)
B <- factor(c(1:3,6,6))

mean(A == B)
Error in Ops.factor(A, B) : level sets of factors are different
```

We can take the `union` of the levels of both factors to get all levels in either factor, and then set remake the factors using that union as the levels. Now, even though the 2 factors have different values, the levels are the same between them and you can compare them:

```
C = factor(A, levels = union(levels(A), levels(B)))
D = factor(B, levels = union(levels(A), levels(B)))

mean(C==D)
[1] 0.6
```

As you can see, the values are unchanged, but the levels are now identical.

```
C
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6

D
[1] 1 2 3 6 6
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```