# Select a dataset based on different column value but in the same row

Tags: r

I have a dataset with around 80 columns and 1000 Rows, a sample of this dataset follow below:

```
ID gend.y gend.x Sire   Dam    Weight 
1   M      F     Jim    jud    220 
2   F      F     josh   linda  198
3   M      NA    Claude Bere   200
4   F      M     John   Mary   350
5   F      F     Peter  Lucy   298
```

And I need select all information that are different between gend.y and gend.x, like this:

```
ID gend.y gend.x Sire   Dam    Weight 
1   M      F     Jim    jud    220 
3   M      NA    Claude Bere   200
4   F      M     John   Mary   350
```

Remember, I need to select the another 76 columns too.

I tried this command:

```
library(dplyr)
new.file=my.file %>%
  filter(gend.y != gend.x)
```

But don't worked. And this message appears:

```
Error in Ops.factor(gend.y, gend.x) : level sets of factors are different
```

Comment: That should work, but without the error message and a reproducible example of your data, there's no way to know why. Please use the `dput` function to output a [mcve] of your data and [edit] it into your question

Comment: Still not a reproducible example, but the error gets you closer. These 2 variables are factors, `The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same set of levels (in the same order).` You probably want to convert them to `character` before comparing, or fix the levels to match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two factors of same length but different levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962082/compare-two-factors-of-same-length-but-different-levels)

Comment: @divibisan, I tried to answer my question. With you'll have suggestions to improve, I appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. If that duplicate solved your problem, I believe there's a button you can press to accept it as a duplicate. This will help other people who find this question  get to the answers they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @divibisan said: "Still not a reproducible example, but the error gets you closer. These 2 variables are factors, The interpretation of a factor depends on both the codes and the "levels" attribute. Be careful only to compare factors with the same set of levels (in the same order). You probably want to convert them to character before comparing, or fix the levels to match."

So I did this (convert them to character):

```
my.file$new.gend.y=as.character(my.file$gend.y)
my.file$new.gend.x=as.character(my.file$gend.x)
```

And after I ran my previous command with the new variables (now converted to character):

```
library(dplyr)
new.file=my.file %>%
  filter(new.gend.y != new.gend.x | is.na(new.gend.y != new.gend.x))
```

And now worked as I expected. Credits @divibisan

Comment: There's no need to use `format`. `format` just specifies how those numbers should be displayed when using the `print` command, it doesn't change anything about the format of the variable. Just `as.character` is plenty.

Comment: I don't know why, but if I don't use `format`, the command ignores some rows that should be considered.

Comment: I think is because the 'NA' rows. Do you agree?

Comment: I think is because the 'NA' rows. Do you agree?

Comment: You can't compare anything with `NA` because `NA` is missing data. So anything `!=  NA` or `== NA` always returns `NA`: without data to compare with, the comparison doesn't mean anything. If you want to select rows with `NA` values, then you need to add an `is.na` test: `filter(new.gend.y != new.gend.x | is.na(new.gend.y != new.gend.x)))` would work

Comment: Better, would be to use NA properly – if the data is really missing, how do you know that `gend.x` for row 3 is different? It could just as easily be `M`, in which case you'd want to exclude that row. If it's just another, different, value, you should change it from `NA` to a specific value

Comment: What format is doing is converting the actual values into printed strings. It's going to mess things up in confusing ways later on, so I would not rely on it. Either add `is.na` checks, or replace `NA` values with a proper, non-missing value if that's appropriate for your data

Comment: Perfect, I got it. And now I corrected our (in the truth yours) answer. Thanks.