# Compare factors with different levels, in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor, forcats

I am trying to compare two factors within a dataframe to create a new variable. The factors have different levels, which is throwing an error.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

mtcars %>% 
  select(gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("gear", "carb"), ~as_factor(.)) %>%
  mutate(gear_vs_carb = gear == carb)
```

And here is the error:

```
Error in Ops.factor(gear, carb) : level sets of factors are different
```

I understand that I can make the comparison by converting the factors to characters or numeric and/or by adding unused levels to the factors to make the levels match, e.g. [How can I compare two factors with different levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962082/how-can-i-compare-two-factors-with-different-levels)

But is it possible to *make the comparison directly with the original factors*?

The output should look the same as for

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate(gear_vs_carb = gear == carb)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `==` wouldn't work with `factor` class.  One option may be to convert to  `character` and do an elementwise comparison or if the intention is to compare the `levels`, `sort` the `levels`, do the comparison and wrap with `all`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   select(gear, carb) %>% 
   mutate_at(c("gear", "carb"), ~as_factor(.)) %>%
   mutate(gear_vs_carb =  all(sort(levels(gear)) == sort(levels(carb))))
   #or use intersect
   #  mutate(gear_vs_carb = length(intersect(levels(gear), 
   #          levels(carb))) == nlevels(gear))
```

---

If we are doing elementwise comparison, convert to `character` class with `as.character` and then do the comparison

```
mtcars %>% 
   select(gear, carb) %>% 
   mutate_at(c("gear", "carb"), ~as_factor(.)) %>%
   mutate(gear_vs_carb = as.character(gear) == as.character(carb))
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to convert one factor to character, not both.

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(gear, carb) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("gear", "carb"), as_factor) %>%
  mutate(gear_vs_carb = gear == as.character(carb))
```